# Why does the JPanel not render correctly when i set my program to fullscreen?

Tags: java, swing, jbutton

I made a JButton that sets my JFrame to fullscreen:

```
    add(fullscreen);

    fullscreen.setSize(100, settings.getHeight());
    fullscreen.setLocation(settings.getX() + (settings.getWidth() / 2) - 50, light.getY() + 35);

    fullscreen.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

        if(isFullscreen) {

            isFullscreen = false;

            screen.ifNotFullscreen();
        }


        if(!isFullscreen) {

            isFullscreen = true;

            screen.ifFullscreen(screen);
        }

        mm.revalidate();
    }
});
```

And here is the JFrame:

```
public class Screen extends JFrame {

    private Kingdomcraft kd;
    private MainMenu mm;
    private Screen screen;
    private Dimension min = new Dimension(800, 600);
    private ImageIcon img;

    public void run() {

        kd = new Kingdomcraft();
        mm = new MainMenu();
        screen = new Screen();
        img = new ImageIcon("assets/textures/items/ItemSwordIron.png");

        this.add(kd);
        this.setContentPane(mm);
        this.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        this.setTitle("Kingdomcraft");
        this.setIconImage(img.getImage());
        this.setBackground(Color.BLACK);
        this.pack();
        this.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        mm.setOpaque(false);
        mm.run();

        if (mm.isFullscreen) {

            ifFullscreen(screen);
        }

        if (!mm.isFullscreen) {

            ifNotFullscreen();
        }
    }

    public void ifFullscreen(Screen screen) {

        this.screen = screen;
        this.setVisible(true);

        GraphicsEnvironment.getLocalGraphicsEnvironment().getDefaultScreenDevice().setFullScreenWindow(screen);

        repaint();
    }

    public void ifNotFullscreen() {

        this.setMinimumSize(min);
        this.setResizable(true);
        this.setVisible(true);

        repaint();
    }
}
```

why is it that when i run the game and select the JButton fullscreen the JPanel renders incorrectly?

And by this I mean there is a big grey JPanel with no JButtons rendered on top of my black background.

Comment: I see no JButton variables anywhere, and certainly none that have been added to your GUI. Please consider creating and posting a [minimal example program](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that reproduces your problem for us.

Comment: well its there i just have trouble filtering all my code finding whats important to include

Comment: the jbutton isnt shown but it is named fullscreen and you can see it once i edit it in

Comment: It's somewhat of an art to do this, but believe me as it's a worthwhile exercise, even if you weren't posting a question here. Often the effort in reducing all distracting code and exposing your problem in all its nakedness leads you yourself to seeing the problem clearly and finding a solution on your own.

Comment: there thats the integrity of my jbutton other than the usual Jbutton fullscreen = new JButton();

Comment: Don't know about the others, but I'm stumped since I cannot compile nor run this code. I'll look back in about an hour to see if you've either gotten a decent answer or had a chance to create the minimal compilable, runnable program. Best of luck!

Comment: when i run my program its all fine. i have several buttons with different purposes not mentioned but if i click this one the program goes fullscreen but it is rendered incorectlly

Comment: Where's MainMenu? If that's not been rendered, understanding what it is doing is very important...

Comment: Plot also looks like you might be running two instances of of your Screen clas, wch would explain why your having issues...

Comment: would it be beneficial to just post the entire 2 class responsible for rendering the screen.

Comment: https://github.com/FeatheredOrcian/Kingdomcraft/blob/master/Kingdomcraft/src/com/pointlight/kingdomcraft/MainMenu.java and https://github.com/FeatheredOrcian/Kingdomcraft/blob/master/Kingdomcraft/src/com/pointlight/kingdomcraft/Screen.java

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is you are creating multiple, distinct, instances of `Screen` but you have absolutely no idea which one is actually visible on the screen.

`Kingdomcraft#main`, creates an instance of `Screen` and calls `screen.run()`, which creates an instance of `Kindomcraft`, `MainMenu` and `Screen`...but wait, we are `Screen`, why do we need another instance?  You then go on to add content to `this` instance of `Screen`, leaving the instance of `screen` blank...

What's really weird, you would pass the instance of `screen` to `ifFullscreen` (this is the blank version) which would then try and make it full screen...with nothing on it...but `ifNotFullscreen` actually uses `this`???

What's even weirder...when you call `MainMenu#run` from `Screen#run`, you create a new instance of `Kingdomcraft`, `MainMenu` and `Screen`...AGAIN...

When the `fullscreen` button is actioned, you are passing it the reference of `screen` you created in `MainMenu`, which is NOT the one that has content on it and which should be displayed on the screen...

Basically, you don't seem to understand what `new` does and the differences between instance of objects.  A new instance has no relationship to any other instances of the same object...

What you should be doing is passing a reference of `Kingdomcraft` to `Screen` and then passing a reference of `Screen` to `MainMenu`.  None of these classes should be creating instances of themselves or instance of `Kingdomcraft` or `Screen`

Each link in the chain should be capable of providing access to the previous link, so that `MainMenu` should be able to ask `Screen` for a reference to `Kingdomcraft` should it need it.

Also, Swing is not thread safe.  You should never be interacting with any component from any thread other than the Event Dispatching Thread.

See [Concurrency in Swing](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/) for more details.

From the looks of things, I think you need to go back to basics and look into how object referencing works...

Comment: Don't be sorry.  Learn.  I was coding when I was 8, ah good old days of gotos and gosubs...

Comment: well anyways  im pretty sure i read somewhere not to mix awt with swing so how do i set fullscreen withought awt

Comment: You shouldn't mix heavy weight components (AWT) with lightweight components (Swing). Swing is based on AWT.  `JFrame` extends from `Frame` which extends from `Window`, which are AWT components.

Comment: ik that Jframe extends frame (ik alot more than you think) its just that stack overflow doesnt allow questions to be broad so it screws me up. anyways i mean i use the GraphicsEnvironment class from awt to make it full screen. is there any other way?

Comment: well.. sorry if that was a dumb q

Comment: Nope, not a dumb question.  The API is looking for information maintained by the parent `Frame`/`Window` class, because `JFrame` is a child of these classes, it's safe to use

Comment: well my dream job was to be a mechanical engineer when i was ten i rigged an rc to drive around with a walkie talkie. this was before the toy producers. 1/2 ago i took up programming... how would you suggest i fix the over use of instances? i do this instead of the conventional way of keeping it all in one class because i have ocd so in my mind it makes more sense to have the main class, the jframe, and jpanel in different class.

Comment: You might also be interested in Lego MindStorm...programmically Lego robots...which, with the right firmware, can be done via Java!

Comment: sorry for my unknowing but i thought by creating an instance i was passing a refrence?.... I know im not realy good at programming and i have a lot to learn but im still proud of whats on that git responsitory

Comment: Nope.  You would need to do something more like `screen.run(kd)`, where `kd` is a reference to an instance of `Kingdomcraft`, otherwise you're just creating new objects in memory which have no connection to each other...