# Why cant I dispose()?

Tags: java, swing, jframe, jpanel, jbutton

I have a dilemma. I am trying to make a game and in the settings there is a button that sets the screen to fullscreen and back to default. The way I did this is i have the JFrame class that i named Screen (I know its more efficient to bundle your swing Components) and a JPanel class I named MainMenu. Now, inside the MainMenu class, I have all your basic buttons and what not. In order for the screen to be set to fullscreen, i created a boolean named isFullscreen. WHen the Jbutton named Fullscreen is pressed the value of this boolean is changed, THEN the Screen class is suppost to dispose of the JFrame and recreate it in fullscreen mode.

Here is my code:

MainMenu

```
    public class MainMenu extends JPanel {

Kingdomcraft kd;
MainMenu mm;
Screen screen;
JButton playSP;
JButton playMP;
JButton settings;
JButton fullscreen;
JButton quit;
JButton createWorld;
JButton addServer;
JSlider sound;
JSlider light;
JList worldList;
JList serverList;
JTextField worldName;
JTextField serverName;
JTextField serverIP;
JButton addNewWorld;
JButton addNewServer;

private Preferences prefs;
private int soundLevel;
private int lightLevel;

public boolean isFullscreen;
public static boolean serverNameFilled = false;
public static boolean serverIPFilled = false;

public void run() {

    kd = new Kingdomcraft();
    mm = new MainMenu();
    screen = new Screen();
    playSP = new JButton("Singleplayer");
    playMP = new JButton("Multiplayer");
    settings = new JButton("Settings");
    fullscreen = new JButton("Fullscreen");
    quit = new JButton("Quit");
    createWorld = new JButton("Create World");
    addServer = new JButton("Add Server");
    sound = new JSlider();
    light = new JSlider();
    prefs = Preferences.userNodeForPackage(MainMenu.class);
    soundLevel = prefs.getInt("SOUND_LEVEL", 50);
    lightLevel = prefs.getInt("LIGHT_LEVEL", 100);
    isFullscreen = prefs.getBoolean("FULLSCREEN", false);
    worldList = new JList();
    serverList = new JList();
    worldName = new JTextField();
    serverName = new JTextField();
    serverIP = new JTextField();
    addNewWorld = new JButton("Add");
    addNewServer = new JButton("Add");

    if (kd.inMainMenu) {

        add(playSP);

        playSP.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

                remove(sound);
                remove(light);
                remove(fullscreen);
                remove(addServer);
                remove(serverName);
                remove(serverIP);
                remove(addNewServer);
                repaint();
                add(createWorld);

                createWorld.setSize(110, 25);
                createWorld.setLocation(playSP.getX() - (playSP.getWidth() / 2) - 5, playSP.getY() + 35);

                createWorld.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

                    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

                        add(worldName);

                        worldName.setSize(110, 25);
                        worldName.setLocation(createWorld.getX(), createWorld.getY() + 35);

                        worldName.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

                            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

                                add(addNewWorld);

                                addNewWorld.setSize(110, 25);
                                addNewWorld.setLocation(worldName.getX(), worldName.getY() + 35);
                            }
                        });
                    }
                });
            }
        });

        add(playMP);

        playMP.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

                remove(sound);
                remove(light);
                remove(fullscreen);
                remove(createWorld);
                remove(worldName);
                remove(addNewWorld);
                repaint();

                add(addServer);

                addServer.setSize(100, 25);
                addServer.setLocation(playMP.getX() - (playMP.getWidth() / 2) - 5, playMP.getY() + 35);

                addServer.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

                    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

                        add(serverName);

                        serverName.setSize(100, 25);
                        serverName.setLocation(addServer.getX(), addServer.getY() + 35);

                        serverName.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

                            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

                                MainMenu.serverNameFilled = true;
                            }
                        });

                        add(serverIP);

                        serverIP.setSize(100, 25);
                        serverIP.setLocation(serverName.getX(), serverName.getY() + 35);

                        serverIP.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

                            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

                                MainMenu.serverIPFilled = true;
                            }
                        });

                        if (serverNameFilled && serverIPFilled) {

                            add(addNewServer);

                            addNewServer.setSize(100, 25);
                            addNewServer.setLocation(serverIP.getX(), serverIP.getY() + 35);

                            addNewServer.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

                                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

                                }
                            });
                        }
                    }
                });
            }
        });

        add(settings);

        settings.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

                remove(createWorld);
                remove(addServer);
                remove(worldName);
                remove(serverName);
                remove(serverIP);
                remove(addNewWorld);
                remove(addNewServer);
                repaint();
                add(sound);

                sound.setSize(settings.getWidth(), settings.getHeight());
                sound.setLocation(settings.getX() + (settings.getWidth() / 2) + 5, settings.getY() + 35);
                sound.setOpaque(false);
                sound.setMinimum(0);
                sound.setMaximum(100);
                sound.setValueIsAdjusting(true);
                sound.setValue(soundLevel);
                sound.setToolTipText("Audio: " + soundLevel + "%");
                sound.addChangeListener(new ChangeListener() {

                    public void stateChanged(ChangeEvent e) {

                        soundLevel = sound.getValue();

                        sound.setToolTipText("Audio: " + soundLevel + "%");

                        prefs.putInt("SOUND_LEVEL", soundLevel);
                    }
                });

                add(light);

                light.setSize(settings.getWidth(), settings.getHeight());
                light.setLocation(sound.getX(), sound.getY() + 35);
                light.setOpaque(false);
                light.setMinimum(50);
                light.setMaximum(150);
                light.setValueIsAdjusting(true);
                light.setValue(lightLevel);
                light.setToolTipText("Brightness: " + lightLevel + "%");
                light.addChangeListener(new ChangeListener() {

                    public void stateChanged(ChangeEvent e) {

                        lightLevel = light.getValue();

                        light.setToolTipText("Brightness: " + lightLevel + "%");

                        prefs.putInt("LIGHT_LEVEL", lightLevel);
                    }
                });

                add(fullscreen);

                fullscreen.setSize(100, settings.getHeight());
                fullscreen.setLocation(settings.getX() + (settings.getWidth() / 2) - 50, light.getY() + 35);

                fullscreen.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

                    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

                        if (!isFullscreen) {

                            isFullscreen = true;

                        } else if(isFullscreen) {

                            isFullscreen = false;
                        }

                        prefs.putBoolean("FULLSCREEN", isFullscreen);

                        screen.dispose();
                        screen.run();
                    }
                });
            }
        });

        add(quit);

        quit.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

                System.exit(ABORT);
            }
        });
    }

    revalidate();
}
    }
```

And the Screen class:

```
    public class Screen extends JFrame {

private Kingdomcraft kd;
private MainMenu mm;
private Dimension min = new Dimension(800, 600);
private ImageIcon img;
private GraphicsDevice gd;
private GraphicsEnvironment ge;

public void run() {

    kd = new Kingdomcraft();
    mm = new MainMenu();
    img = new ImageIcon("assets/textures/items/ItemSwordIron.png");
    ge = GraphicsEnvironment.getLocalGraphicsEnvironment();
    gd = ge.getDefaultScreenDevice();

    add(kd);
    setContentPane(mm);
    setMinimumSize(min);
    setTitle("Kingdomcraft");
    setIconImage(img.getImage());
    setBackground(Color.BLACK);
    setLocation(WIDTH / 2, HEIGHT / 2);
    setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    setVisible(true);
    pack();

    mm.setOpaque(false);
    mm.run();

    if (mm.isFullscreen) {

        setResizable(false);
        gd.setFullScreenWindow(this);
        repaint();
    }

}

    }
```

Though you roughly only need to view this code, from the MainMenu class, and the Screen class:

```
    add(fullscreen);

                fullscreen.setSize(100, settings.getHeight());
                fullscreen.setLocation(settings.getX() + (settings.getWidth() / 2) - 50, light.getY() + 35);

                fullscreen.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

                    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

                        if (!isFullscreen) {

                            isFullscreen = true;

                        } else if(isFullscreen) {

                            isFullscreen = false;
                        }

                        prefs.putBoolean("FULLSCREEN", isFullscreen);

                        screen.dispose();
                        screen.run();
                            }
```

My problem is that no matter how long I try and search it doesn't dispose of the screen class though it does create a new window with the correct screen size. I don't want multiple windows.

What I've tried:

creating a method inside the Screen class that disposes the screen and going int the JButton and adding screen.end(); no luck. Please help meh...

EDIT:

new code:

Screen class:

```
    public class Screen {

private MainMenu mm;
private Dimension min = new Dimension(800, 600);
private ImageIcon img;
private GraphicsDevice gd;
private GraphicsEnvironment ge;

public static JFrame frame;

public void run() {

    mm = new MainMenu();
    img = new ImageIcon("assets/textures/items/ItemSwordIron.png");
    ge = GraphicsEnvironment.getLocalGraphicsEnvironment();
    gd = ge.getDefaultScreenDevice();
    frame = new JFrame();

    frame.add(new Kingdomcraft());
    frame.setContentPane(mm);
    frame.setMinimumSize(min);
    frame.setTitle("Kingdomcraft");
    frame.setIconImage(img.getImage());
    frame.setBackground(Color.BLACK);
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.setVisible(true);
    frame.pack();

    mm.setOpaque(false);
    mm.run();

    if (mm.isFullscreen) {

        frame.setResizable(false);
        gd.setFullScreenWindow(frame);
        frame.repaint();
    }

}

    }
```

MainMenu:

```
    public class MainMenu extends JPanel {

Screen screen;
JButton playSP;
JButton playMP;
JButton settings;
JButton fullscreen;
JButton quit;
JButton createWorld;
JButton addServer;
JSlider sound;
JSlider light;
JTextField worldName;
JTextField serverName;
JTextField serverIP;
JButton addNewWorld;
JButton addNewServer;

private Preferences prefs;
private int soundLevel;
private int lightLevel;

public boolean isFullscreen;
public static boolean serverNameFilled = false;
public static boolean serverIPFilled = false;

public void run() {

    screen = new Screen();
    playSP = new JButton("Singleplayer");
    playMP = new JButton("Multiplayer");
    settings = new JButton("Settings");
    fullscreen = new JButton("Fullscreen");
    quit = new JButton("Quit");
    createWorld = new JButton("Create World");
    addServer = new JButton("Add Server");
    sound = new JSlider();
    light = new JSlider();
    prefs = Preferences.userNodeForPackage(MainMenu.class);
    soundLevel = prefs.getInt("SOUND_LEVEL", 50);
    lightLevel = prefs.getInt("LIGHT_LEVEL", 100);
    isFullscreen = prefs.getBoolean("FULLSCREEN", false);
    worldName = new JTextField();
    serverName = new JTextField();
    serverIP = new JTextField();
    addNewWorld = new JButton("Add");
    addNewServer = new JButton("Add");

    if (new Kingdomcraft().inMainMenu) {

        add(playSP);

        playSP.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

                remove(sound);
                remove(light);
                remove(fullscreen);
                remove(addServer);
                remove(serverName);
                remove(serverIP);
                remove(addNewServer);
                repaint();
                add(createWorld);

                createWorld.setSize(110, 25);
                createWorld.setLocation(playSP.getX() - (playSP.getWidth() / 2) - 5, playSP.getY() + 35);

                createWorld.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

                    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

                        add(worldName);

                        worldName.setSize(110, 25);
                        worldName.setLocation(createWorld.getX(), createWorld.getY() + 35);

                        worldName.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

                            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

                                add(addNewWorld);

                                addNewWorld.setSize(110, 25);
                                addNewWorld.setLocation(worldName.getX(), worldName.getY() + 35);
                            }
                        });
                    }
                });
            }
        });

        add(playMP);

        playMP.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

                remove(sound);
                remove(light);
                remove(fullscreen);
                remove(createWorld);
                remove(worldName);
                remove(addNewWorld);
                repaint();

                add(addServer);

                addServer.setSize(100, 25);
                addServer.setLocation(playMP.getX() - (playMP.getWidth() / 2) - 5, playMP.getY() + 35);

                addServer.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

                    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

                        add(serverName);

                        serverName.setSize(100, 25);
                        serverName.setLocation(addServer.getX(), addServer.getY() + 35);

                        serverName.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

                            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

                                MainMenu.serverNameFilled = true;
                            }
                        });

                        add(serverIP);

                        serverIP.setSize(100, 25);
                        serverIP.setLocation(serverName.getX(), serverName.getY() + 35);

                        serverIP.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

                            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

                                MainMenu.serverIPFilled = true;
                            }
                        });

                        if (serverNameFilled && serverIPFilled) {

                            add(addNewServer);

                            addNewServer.setSize(100, 25);
                            addNewServer.setLocation(serverIP.getX(), serverIP.getY() + 35);

                            addNewServer.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

                                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

                                }
                            });
                        }
                    }
                });
            }
        });

        add(settings);

        settings.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

                remove(createWorld);
                remove(addServer);
                remove(worldName);
                remove(serverName);
                remove(serverIP);
                remove(addNewWorld);
                remove(addNewServer);
                repaint();
                add(sound);

                sound.setSize(settings.getWidth(), settings.getHeight());
                sound.setLocation(settings.getX() + (settings.getWidth() / 2) + 5, settings.getY() + 35);
                sound.setOpaque(false);
                sound.setMinimum(0);
                sound.setMaximum(100);
                sound.setValueIsAdjusting(true);
                sound.setValue(soundLevel);
                sound.setToolTipText("Audio: " + soundLevel + "%");
                sound.addChangeListener(new ChangeListener() {

                    public void stateChanged(ChangeEvent e) {

                        soundLevel = sound.getValue();

                        sound.setToolTipText("Audio: " + soundLevel + "%");

                        prefs.putInt("SOUND_LEVEL", soundLevel);
                    }
                });

                add(light);

                light.setSize(settings.getWidth(), settings.getHeight());
                light.setLocation(sound.getX(), sound.getY() + 35);
                light.setOpaque(false);
                light.setMinimum(50);
                light.setMaximum(150);
                light.setValueIsAdjusting(true);
                light.setValue(lightLevel);
                light.setToolTipText("Brightness: " + lightLevel + "%");
                light.addChangeListener(new ChangeListener() {

                    public void stateChanged(ChangeEvent e) {

                        lightLevel = light.getValue();

                        light.setToolTipText("Brightness: " + lightLevel + "%");

                        prefs.putInt("LIGHT_LEVEL", lightLevel);
                    }
                });

                add(fullscreen);

                fullscreen.setSize(100, settings.getHeight());
                fullscreen.setLocation(settings.getX() + (settings.getWidth() / 2) - 50, light.getY() + 35);

                fullscreen.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

                    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

                        if (!isFullscreen) {

                            isFullscreen = true;

                        } else if(isFullscreen) {

                            isFullscreen = false;
                        }

                        prefs.putBoolean("FULLSCREEN", isFullscreen);

                        Screen.frame.dispose();
                        screen.run();
                    }
                });
            }
        });

        add(quit);

        quit.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

                System.exit(ABORT);
            }
        });
    }

    revalidate();
}
    }
```

Comment: As outlined in [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22463982/why-does-the-jpanel-not-render-correctly-when-i-set-my-program-to-fullscreen/22467498#22467498) you are creating multiple, independent instance of your objects, so the `Screen` you are trying to `dispose` probably isn't the one that is on the screen.  You need to create a single instance of these classes and pass them to those objects that need them...

Comment: Im sorry yea that was my old post i cant see any simple way to create one.

Comment: If i were creating multiple instances of Screen wouldn't more than one appear on my toolbar? also wouldn't it just dispose of all Instances of Screen?

Comment: Would doing this be just as bad? add(new Kingdomcraft());

Comment: What if i maid everything static so i didnt have to create instances of them? 0.o

Comment: Truth is... I knew how to do it all along... i just didnt wanna do it that way...

Comment: DO NOT use `static`, this is a good sign of a bad design, pass a reference of the objects required to each instance of the classes that need them

Comment: To those wo ever find themselfs at tis Just remember... instead of extending Jframe create a new JFrame called frame... yata yata yata... ocd breakdown...

Comment: ik... i just hate the fact that screen cant extend JFrame...

Comment: Technically it can, your just not adding any value to the class...it also looks you into a single container, meaning that you `Screen` is not portable...

Comment: Btw, pay attention to variable names. If someone new works with your code and wants to use a value from your light JSlider, how should he know it is named as 'light'? :P He has to investigate declarations, and loose a couple of seconds, at least :) For UI comps I prefere to use btnSettings, sliderLight or sth similar. Than, if you want to use slider, you type 'slider', make CTRL+Space (in Eclipse), and you see all sliders in your class :) Saves much time. Consider this :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As outlined in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22463982/why-does-the-jpanel-not-render-correctly-when-i-set-my-program-to-fullscreen/22467498#22467498), you are creating multiple instances of your classes and some how expecting them to know about each other...

`new Screen(); new Screen()` creates two distinct instances of your class, each one is it's own `JFrame`, they have nothing to do with each other...

Starting with `Kingdomcraft`...

```
private Screen screen;

public Kingdomcraft() {
    EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            screen = new Screen(Kingdomcraft.this);
        }
    });
}

//...

public static void main(String[] args) {

    Kingdomcraft kd = new Kingdomcraft();
    // This does nothing...
    //Screen screen = new Screen();
    kd.start();
    //screen.run();

}
```

Remove all `new Screen()` and `new MainMenu()` from this class...

In `Screen`...

```
public class Screen extends JFrame {

    private Kingdomcraft kd;
    private MainMenu mm;
    private Dimension min = new Dimension(800, 600);
    private ImageIcon img;

    public Screen(Kingdomcraft kingdomcraft) {
        kd = kingdomcraft;

        mm = new MainMenu(this);
        //...
    }

    public Kingdomcraft getKingdomcraft() {
        return kd;
    }
```

Remove all `new Kingdomcraft()` and `new Screen()` from this class.  You will need to change the reference to `screen` to `this` or `Screen.this` for inner classes...

Equally, you could just pass the reference of `Kingdomcraft` to `MainMenu` along with screen, but this is just another way of doing it...

And `MainMenu`

```
public class MainMenu extends JPanel {

    Screen screen;
    //...

    public MainMenu(Screen srn) {

        this.screen = srn;
        //...
        if (screen.getKingdomcraft().inMainMenu) {
```

You're going to have to remove all `new Kingdomcraft()`, `new Screen()` and `new MainMenu()`  from this class...

Comment: I just went in my Screen class and made it so that instead of extending  it with JFrame i created an object of JFrame

Comment: I posted the new code

Comment: Don't make `frame` static (in fact it's not a good idea to make it `public`), don't create a new instance `Kingdomcraft`, use the reference that was passed to you...

Comment: THanks for the help sorry I didn't Acknowledge you the first time you answered this question... maybe in the future when im bett er at programming i can come back and make Screen extend JFrame and do everything the correct way

Comment: I think the way you've done it (having a separate `JFrame` instance) is better

Comment: You mean as in havving the Jframe in its own class?

Comment: No, I mean like the way you've updated in you question...

Comment: but is it that bad to isolate my jframe?

Comment: You code structure (IMHO) is a little odd.  Personally, I would have `Kingdomcraft` just as the main entry point for the application, not extending anything.  In there, I would create a `JFrame` and add the `Screen` to it.  The `Screen` would then create the `MainMenu` and the "game surface" which would used to actually render the game...

Comment: Yea Im aware of all the different conventions, it's just that i

Comment: have had ocd since a kid, i'd be called down to the office at school to organize the book shelfs

Comment: ok i will leave you alone i understand im babbling